# Using an external class for handling bar code scanner input?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, barcode-scanner, keyboardfocusmanager

I'm building a basic Point of Sale application and I've been looking for ways of having my main POS JFrame listen for bar code input. I found this code (slightly modified) posted by Cyrusmith, which looks like what I want but I don't know how to implement it in my JFrame. It looks like its intended to be a separate class, which is how I have it in my project currently. I asked my coworker and he doesn't know either.

Thanks for your help.

```
package barcode;

import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

/**
 *   Listens for bar code input and puts it into a String Buffer.
 *
 */
public class BarcodeReader {

    private static final long THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int MIN_BARCODE_LENGTH = 8;

    public interface BarcodeListener {

        void onBarcodeRead(String barcode);
    }
    private final StringBuffer barcode = new StringBuffer();
    private final List<BarcodeListener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    private long lastEventTimeStamp = 0L;

    public BarcodeReader() {

        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                try {
                    if (e.getID() != KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (e.getWhen() - lastEventTimeStamp > THRESHOLD) {
                        barcode.delete(0, barcode.length());
                    }

                    lastEventTimeStamp = e.getWhen();

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                        if (barcode.length() >= MIN_BARCODE_LENGTH) {
                            fireBarcode(barcode.toString());
                        }
                        barcode.delete(0, barcode.length());
                    } else {
                        barcode.append(e.getKeyChar());
                    }
                    return false;
                } catch (UnsupportedOperationException err) {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(err); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }

            }
        });

    }

    protected void fireBarcode(String barcode) {
        for (BarcodeListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onBarcodeRead(barcode);
        }
    }

    public void addBarcodeListener(BarcodeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeBarcodeListener(BarcodeListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most bar code readers basically inject the codes directly into the keyboard buffer.  So if you had a `JTextField` which had keyboard focus, the resulting text would be "entered" directly into it...no magic involved.

If you "want" to use this reader, then you will need to create an instance...

```
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
```

Register a `BarcodeListener` to it...

```
reader.addBarcodeListener(new BarcodeListener() {
    public void onBarcodeRead(String barcode) {
        // Respond to the event, like, I don't know,
        // set the text of text field :P
    }
});
```

But to me, this just seems like a lot of extra work - but that's just me...

So, yes, it's suppose to be a separate class.  Depending on what you want to achieve, you could dump somewhere in your current code base, `import` the class into your source code and use it like any other.  Equally, you could create a separate library for it, but this just means you need to include it within the classpath for compiling and runtime execution as well...